# Is there an easy way of choosing a random person to be assigned to a team in Lua/Roblox Studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have not found any solutions to the issue I'm having. I am currently attempting:

```
local SniperTeam = game.Teams.Sniper

if #game.Players:GetPlayers() < 2 then
repeat
wait()
until #game.Players:GetPlayers() > 1
end

local players = game.Players:GetPlayers()
local playerChosen = math.Random(1, #players)
playerChosen.Team = game.Teams.Sniper
```

And I get no errors, but when I attempt it in game, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `math.random` (lower case m)

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.7

Unrelated, but you can simplify your repeat loop using

```lua
while #game.Players:GetPlayers() < 2 do
    wait()
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your developer console (f9 on your keyboard)